# Taxonomy vs Values module in my case

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms, users

I'm using the [Values module](https://drupal.org/project/values) for creating a list of subscriptions the user can choose of when they register (it's a field in the registration form). Now I've seen I can also create a list with the Taxonomy module. I'm just curious what's the best practice for this? Should I use the module already implemented or is Values module better in my case?

Comment: "Should I use the module already implemented or is Values module better in my case?" - Did you mean is taxonomy module better?

Comment: Yes, what's the best use in my case?

Comment: "The best way" is always subjective. Which module you should use depends only from which module implements the features you want. Just test the module you think to use, and see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Values module is a *field* for users to enter their own list of values in a key-value format.

Core taxonomy module is used to create lists of terms which can be placed as a *field* on the registration form using a 'term reference'. This would then appear as either a select list, radios or checkboxes (checkboxes if the field is multi select).

The difference is that with Values, users enter their own values and with term reference and Taxonomy, users choose from your list of terms in the taxonomy. Which do you want? I think if you're looking for subscriptions, it's term reference and Taxonomy.

Comment: What do you mean with users? The admin needs the opportunity to edit this list.. And with values you can also add a value set where the admin can add or change values.

Comment: I haven't used Values actually, but I presumed that the user can alter the values to be whatever they want. If you don't want users to enter whatever they want, use Taxonomy where the admin chooses the terms which appear on the list. This is the most popular use case, I've used this many times and have never used Values module.